# How is the area of an arbitrary triangle and area of a parallelogram related?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, cross-product

In am reading a vector algebra book, it says

```
Theorem x.x says magnitude of the
cross product P × Q is equal to the area of the parallelogram whose sides are
formed by the vectors P and Q. As a consequence, the area A of an arbitrary tri-
angle whose vertices are given by the points V1, V2, and V3 can be calculated us-
ing formula 
-- Snippet from the book
```

$$A = \frac{1}{2}||(v_{2} - v_{1})X(v_{3}-v_{1})||$$

this piece of information is not even related to the vector product topic I am studying. I cannot understand how the area of an arbitrary triangle is dependent on the $PXQ$ value we've just derived?

Can some one explain to me what the above block quote line means?

Comment: The triangle and the paralellogram are not both "arbitrary"! The triangle  is one half of the parallelogram..

Comment: I just wanted to know how did the formula A=1/2||(v2−v1)(v3−v1)|| even is related to ||P|| ||Q|| sin alpha the we just derived, I mean that's what the sentence from the book says right?

Comment: @RamachandraJunior The area of a triangle is $\,\frac{1}{2}ab \sin C\,$, see [here](http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/trig/area.html) for example.

Comment: @dxiv so its like $\frac{1}{2} ||P|| . ||Q|| . sin \alpha$, where $||P|| sin \alpha$ is the height as it is the projection of P perpendicular to Q? That actually solves the problem. Well done mate!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich got what you meant now bro!

Answer (score 2):

Given a triangle $\triangle ABC$, draw $CD$ and $BD$ parallel to $AB$ and $AC$ respectively, giving a parallelogram $ABDC$. The area of $\triangle ABC$ is clearly one half the area of the parallelogram, so it is
$$\frac{1}{2}\lVert AB\times AC\rVert.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us make sense out of  $$A = \frac{1}{2}||(v_{2} - v_{1})(v_{3}-v_{1})||$$First, we notice that $ v_{2} - v_{1}$ and $v_{3}-v_{1}$ are vectors.

The norm of the cross product of these vectors gives us the area of the parallelogram whose sides are formed by these vectors. The area of the triangle formed by these vectors is half of the area of the parallelogram. Thus

$$A = \frac{1}{2}||(v_{2} - v_{1})\times (v_{3}-v_{1})||$$ makes more sense.

Comment: Cross products are defined on vectors so $v_2 -v_1$ must be a vector so the crass product makes sense.

Comment: Yes it does @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani, I've changed all to cross product

Comment: Excellent!  Now you have a very good proof.

Comment: thanks for appreciation and your efforts @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Reverse Engineering**

Okay this is what I have until now,

$A = \frac{1}{2}||(v2−v1)X(v3−v1)||$

now vertices can be considered as displacement of point from origin. source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10640261/8526133

so let us say v1 is at the origin and thus a zero vector for simplification

$$ v2 - v1 = v2 $$
$$ v3 - v1 = v3 $$

so now the equation is

$$\frac{1}{2}||v2 X v3||$$ 
$$\frac{1}{2} * ||v2|| * ||v3|| * sin\alpha$$

so $||v2||$ becomes the base and $||v3|| sin \alpha $ becomes height

as we know $1/2 * b* h$ and also this is half the area of parallelogram and also the half of the cross product of two vectors.

pardone my drawing skill but here's a
[supporting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIDXi.png)

thanks to @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani, @dxiv, @David C. Ullrich(triangle and parallelogram are not arbitrary).

Comment: The notation may be confusing. The point (3,5) could be considered as a vector with the initial point at the origin and the terminal at (3,5).

Comment: well as you know the actual origin never matters in case of vectors its always the starting point of the vector, of course its the usage of vertices in vector topics that brings confusion.

Comment: Actually the final result is the same even if you start at (3, 5) or (x, y ) (as you probably know already)

Comment: I just wanted to connect the dots back to basics. If I want something perfect, I'd stick with the text books one liner, I'd be glad if you could improve and strike the same intuition @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani.